# Removing g++ warning for template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have a simple class:

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
class Int
{
    bool valid(size_t index) { return index >= N; }
    T t;
}
```

If I define an instance of this class as:

```
Int<0, Widget> zero;
```

I get a g++ warning:

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

I tried to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to partially specialize a function with a non-type template parameter.
It looks like it might not be possible to disable this warning in g++.  What is the proper way to either hide this warning, or to write this method such that it always returns true if N==0?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the full range of `size_t`, or could you go with a signed type?

Comment: @Bill: Unfortunately I need the whole range :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I've come up with the following solution:

```
template<size_t N>
bool GreaterThanOrEqual(size_t index)
{
    return index >= N;
}

template<>
bool GreaterThanOrEqual<0l>(size_t index)
{
    return true;
}
```

So now, the class looks like:

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
class Int
{
    bool valid(size_t index) { return GreaterThanOrEqual<N>(index); }
    T t;
}
```

Of course, I get an unused parameter warning, but there are ways around that....

Is this a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can specialize int for N = 0.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I don't think you can partially specialize a function with a non-type template parameter.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: template <typename T> class Int<0, T> { ... }

Comment: Thanks.  The class is actually more complicated then my simple example, so specializing the whole class isn't an option.  Is there a way to only specialize the valid() function?